# Is the JSONP only solution if I need to make a CORS required jQuery.Ajax POST call?

Tags: jquery, jsonp, http-post, cors

I need to make calls to a WCF RESTful service sitting on a different domain.

I do HTTP POST calls via jQuery.Ajax.

The reason I wanted to make a HTTP POST instead of GET was I had some special characters in my JavaScript object's properties; and I didn't want to loose time on handling with this.

It works fine with IE9 but fails on FF and IE8
(See related question if interested: 
[Why it fails?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855427/what-is-wrong-here-so-that-ie9-can-do-cors-ajax-call-but-ie8-and-firefox-can-not)

People suggests me to use JSONP.

**Question**:
Isn't there any other quicker way to make CORS required jQuery.Ajax HTTP POST calls which would work for all browsers -without needing JSONP?

Comment: You can't POST with jsonp anyway.

Comment: So either make a HTTP GET with JSONP for CORS support OR forget about jQuery.Ajax HTTP POST call with CORS support that can work for ALL modern browser?

Comment: CORS and JSONP are two completely different things. JSONP is not CORS, it's simply including a <script> on your page. CORS involves the cross-origin allowing the client access to it.

Answer (score 1):

You can proxy the HTTP request through your server. And then you don't need JSONP

Comment: Any example are you aware of where I can have a look?

Answer (score 0):

If you have control over the RESTful service, you can add this headers in your service response:

`'Access-Control-Allow-Methods', 'POST'`

`'Access-Control-Allow-Origin', 'YOUR_CLIENT_DOMAIN'`

With this headers you can bypass the CORS in the browser.

Comment: I have : 
         <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="*"

Comment: web.config at the place where my WCF is hosted under IIS 7.5

Comment: (If you are interested to help me to figure out the problem, you can see all the details of the issue in the :
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14855427/what-is-wrong-here-so-that-ie9-can-do-cors-ajax-call-but-ie8-and-firefox-can-not